# Recursive Knapsack

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to implement recursive Knapsack I used the common algorithm to write it as following:

```
int pack(int n, int s) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (List[n].s > s)
        return pack(n-1, s);
    else {
        int max =  Math.max(pack(n-1,s), pack(n-1, s -List[n].s) + List[n].v);
        return max;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can know which items were packed?

Update: I want only the items that belong to best choice and I don't want to change the function header.

**EDIT** Using array to track items, what's wrong with this?

```
int pack(int n , int s)
{
     if(n < 0)
     {
         counter =0;
         return 0;
     }
     if (itemsList[n].s > s)
     {
        return pack(n-1, s);
     }
     else
     {
         int max1 = pack(n-1,s);
         int max2 = pack(n-1, s - itemsList[n].s) + itemsList[n].v ;

        if(max2 > max1)
        {
            flag1[counter] = new item();
            flag1[counter] = itemsList[n];
            counter ++;
        }
         return max(max1, max2);
     }         
}
```

Comment: this will return all the trials before finding the best choice of items, I want only the packed ones

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
int pack(int n, int s) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (List[n].s > s)
        return pack(n-1, s);
    else {
        int without = pack(n-1,s);
        int with = pack(n-1, s-List[n].s) + List[n].v;
        if (with >= without) {
            System.out.println(n);                
        }
        return Math.max(with, without);
    }
}
```

or, you can return the list of results:

```
int pack(int n, int s) {
    return reallyPack(n, s, new ArrayList<Item>());
}

int reallyPack(int n, int s, List<Item> l) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (List[n].s > s)
        return reallyPack(n-1, s);
    else {
        int without = reallyPack(n-1,s);
        int with = reallyPack(n-1, s-List[n].s) + List[n].v;
        if (with >= without) {
            l.add(itemsList[n]);
        }
        return Math.max(with, without);
    }
}
```

and of course, you still know how many items were selected: this is simply the size of the returned list.

Comment: Didn't return the best choice, returned another one !

Comment: What were the input data and what was printed ?

Comment: This is the input data: 7 7 9 5 12 14 6 12 3 4 2 6 7 3 5
it should sum up to 34 using 7,9,6,12 with space 15 only.

The result was 6,12,5,12 with value 35 and space 16 !

Comment: So you provided the V array, what was the S array ? And did you call pack with s = 15 or 16 ?

Comment: in fact I tried printing and it's working the last four prints were 0,1,5,6 but what I need to do is to store those items in an array, so I think managing the index of that array is the problem !

Comment: This input is both V and S arrays .. 7 is the number of items, first 7 items are v and second 7 items are s.

Comment: and I called with s = 15

Comment: Can you please check the update in the original post?

Comment: This works, of course. It would be much cleaner to pass a List as a parameter of the method or to return it in addition to s, but if you don't want to do that, you can do it with a class field, as you did.

Comment: Your counter should be set to 0 before pack is called, not inside pack (and this is really dirty).

Comment: Edited to show how you can return the list of all selected items.

Comment: This program may print something on **every** recursive call. It may print a item more than 1 time and the complete number of print calls may even be greater than `List.length`. Also `reallyPack` is not always used with the correct number of arguments in the second code sniplet.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of all items that are currently selected (using e.g. `boolean[]` field). Then you have to remember the max in the calls of pack with `n < 0`.

```
int maximum;
int currentMax;
boolean[] packed;
boolean[] maxPacked;

int pack(int n, int s) {
    if (n < 0) {
        if (maximum < currentMax) {
            // found better selection
            maximum = currentMax;
            // copy array
            for (int i = 0; i < packed.length; i++)
                 maxPacked[i] = packed[i];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    packed[n] = false;
    int maxWithout = pack(n-1, s);
    if (List[n].s > s) {
        return maxWithout;
    } else {
        packed[n] = true;
        currentMax += List[n].v;
        int maxWith = pack(n-1, s -List[n].s) + List[n].v;
        currentMax -= List[n].v;

        return Math.max(maxWith, maxWithout);
    }
}

void callingFunction() {
    int maxCost = //...;
    // always possible to choose no items
    maximum = 0;
    currentMax = 0;
    packed = new boolean[List.length];
    maxPacked = new boolean[List.length];

    pack(List.length-1, maxCost);
    // print best selection
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxPacked));
}
```